# Mobile Tools frontpage for mobiles problem

Tags: 6, theming

I have Mobile tools 2.x-dev version installed at this moment.

Device detection and theme switching is working properly. But frontpage for mobiles specified in mobile tools settings, does not work. In mobile version I'm viewing desktop version frontpage.

I'm using m.domain.com for mobile version.

Also I noticed that if I go mobile frontpage URL (which is /mobile), I also receive desktop version frontpage (which is /front).

**Edited:** this is bug. http://drupal.org/node/1197570

Comment: Have you changed your front page of mobile sites in admin/settings/mobile-tools ?(Expand the "Additional Settings" field set)
You have to set it to /mobile and it will work then.

Comment: I have changed it ofcourse :) I have updated question.